# Visual Basic 2010, recognizing last two digits of a number

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In visual basic 2010, I am trying to take a number that has been selected in a `listbox` and add the last two digits of the selected number, to a running total. The possible numbers that can be selected are all 4 digits.

(ex: number selected from `listbox` = `1712`. I want to make `c = c + 12`) but i want to do this for any number selected.

if it helps, the numbers in the `listbox` range from `1700 - 2400`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator, in VB it's `Mod`

`c = c + (<numberFromListBox> Mod 100)`

Comment: I completely understand why this should work. I understand the mod function, however, it isn't. Is it maybe not recognizing the selected item as an integer?

Comment: You could put it in debug mode and see?

Comment: Wow nevermind i figured it out! Stupid mistake on my part. Thank you very much. I didn't even think of the mod function

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
total+=CDbl(Mid(Listbox.SelectedItems(0),3))
```